# Why pasted folder is arranged to the place of My Computer on desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, copy-paste

When I copy and paste a folder to the desktop, it automatically arranged at the top left (the place of My Computer)? My settings are as shown below. Any idea to fix the problem?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bAD7.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bnLd.png)

Comment: I have the same setting as yours and the folder will be pasted to the place that my mouse pointer is. You might check if you can copy and paste at the mouse location.

Comment: I solved the problem with the help of @Candy, many thanks. 

To fix the problem I just left click of the mouse button before paste instead of directly ricght click and paste.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the copy and paste options from the mouse.
Do not use Control C and then Control V

Highlight the folder by hovering over it. Press & Hold Ctrl key. Drag a copy of the folder anywhere onto any desktop onto any monitor and it will stay there.